# If an app gives me the System.ArgumentOutofRangeException, does that mean it is a bug in the app?

Tags: .net

I have this problem with an app of a printer. I need to know if it is an error in my installation or a bug in the app. I think it is a bug (programmer didn't catch this exception), and I suspect this app is made in C# and they didn't noticed the uncaught exception when they upgraded their printers (The fact is that they added a character in the printer's and the driver's name, and the Exception was thrown because of the driver's name).

Comment: You need to ask the vendor or whoever wrote your code to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trace where exception is thrown, and handle it in your application.
Maybe you parameters are incorrect.
To be sure that application is written on C# or any other .NET language  - use Reflector.
If it shows you a project source tree - app is written on .NET.
Or contact application support.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted tech support but it can take a day or two to reply. I know the support process and I want to avoid the steps of: "check your installation, your operating system, conflicts with other programs, etc". maybe I sound a little desperate, but the companny where I work re-sells these printers and we need the apps working ok.